# Switch case examination in c

Tags: c, switch-statement

So I came across this very simple problem using switch case in c and I wanted some explanation on it.

```
int function(int x)
{
    switch(x)
    {
        case 1: return 1;
        case 2: function(x-1);
        case 3: return -1;
    }
}

int main(){
    int x = 2;
    function(x);
}
```

Of course its extremely simple but what I dont get is this.
When the code executes and gets inside case 2, since there is no `break;` it will go to case 3 *BUT* since the function is doing a recursion shouldn't it first follow the recursion through?

So no it doesn't and the output is:

```
-1
```

While I thought it would be:

```
1
```

Why is that?

Comment: Can you show us the actual function call?

Comment: Yes, it follows the recursion, but what happens when the call to `function(x-1)` returns?

Comment: What 'output'? Please paste the whole relevant code.

Comment: There is no relevant code that's that, I have just written it from memory.

Comment: Okay thank you all for your answers, I get it now, since you all are correct and made me understand it, I'll accept the one with the most votes. Perhaps I was being an idiot and didn't follow through :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `function(2)`, you do make a recursive call, but this value is never used.  So the `switch` statement proceeds to the third case where it returns `-1`.

The sequence of events is:

```
// first function call
case 2: function(1);   // recursive call

// inside recursive call
case 1: return 1;      // return 1

// back in first function call
case 3: return -1;     // return -1 to the caller, having ignored the return
                       // value from case 2
```

Answer (score 2):

> Of course its extremely simple but what I dont get is this. When the code executes and gets inside case 2, since there is no break; it will go to case 3 BUT since the function is doing a recursion shouldn't it first follow the recursion through?

You are right about the program's control flow. But let's see what happens step by step.

- First, we have the main function, calling the `function` with value `2`.
- We then get into `function`. When the function reaches `case 2`, it calls itself again recursively with argument `1`.
- The called function `function` reaches `case 1`, which it matches, and follows the instructions inside.
- So the call ed function `function` ***returns*** a value `1`, without anything else happening.
- Consequently, `function` will continue to `case 3` (since there is no `break` statement as you also pointed out) and will print `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

The program control flow *is* as you think it should be - it does perform one recursive call, with `case 1:` being ran that time. But you are **discarding** that `return` value from `case 2:`. Program control then runs into `case 3:`, with that result being returned.

It would have been a different matter had you written

`case 2: return function(x-1);`

instead.

Answer (score -2):

I encountered with a similar problem when I was using switch cases for checking whether the entered character is vowel or not , without using break statement in switch cases.

And in the output it showed me both the cases as:-
It is a vowel.
It is not a vowel

Later on I found out that if you don't write break statement with the cases then the compiler will execute all the cases and gets terminated from the switch cases and moves for the further steps in your code.

Comment: OP apparently is aware of fall-through. This might be a comment, but it is not an answer.